# Add a prefix to a calculated output (currency)

Tags: javascript, html, prefix, calc

I have the following simple calculation which adds two values together. These values relate to the Rand (South African currency) which is identified using an "R" as a prefix).

```js
function calculate() {
    var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("A").value);
    var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("B").value);
    var total = A+B;
  
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" placeholder="First amount in R"> +
<input type="text" id="B" placeholder="Second amount in R">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> = 
<output id="total">R</output>
```

Is it possible for the output value to include "R" as a permanent prefix? For example, 4 + 4 = **R8**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes sure you've just to Add the `R` prefix to the output result, like :

```
document.getElementById("total").value = 'R' + total;
```

**Working snippet :**

```js
function calculate() {
  var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("A").value);
  var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var total = A + B;

  document.getElementById("total").value = 'R' + total;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" placeholder="First amount in R"> +
<input type="text" id="B" placeholder="Second amount in R">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> =
<output id="total">R</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract that text instead of adding it explicitly. This way you can add it dynamically:

```js
function calculate() {
  let el = document.getElementById("total");
  let txt = el.value.match(/(\w)/)[0]; // extract the text 'R'

  var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("A").value);
  var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("B").value);
  var total = A + B;

  el.value = txt + total;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" placeholder="First amount in R"> +
<input type="text" id="B" placeholder="Second amount in R">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> =
<output id="total">R</output>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native `Intl.NumberFormat` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat

```
var total = new Intl.NumberFormat('af-NA',
  { style: 'currency', currency: 'ZAR' }).format(A + B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply append `string R` before your output like this:

```js
function calculate() {
    var A = parseFloat(document.getElementById("A").value);
    var B = parseFloat(document.getElementById("B").value);
    var total = A+B;
  
  document.getElementById("total").value = `R${total}`;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="A" placeholder="First amount in R"> +
<input type="text" id="B" placeholder="Second amount in R">
<input type="button" onClick="calculate()" value="Calculate"> = 
<b><output id="total">R</output></b>
```